# Best way to update package version from pyproject.toml file

Tags: python-3.x, python-poetry

My workflow embeds a `__version__` package variable in the **init**.py for the package.  When updating the package version with poetry using `poetry version patch` (or similar) I want my embedded `__version__` variable updated as well.

I currently use a pre-commit hook (git) like this:

```
#!/bin/bash


read name version < <(poetry version)

read pversion < <(python -c  "from ${name} import __version__;print(__version__)")

init=${name}/__init__.py

if [[ "${pversion}" != "${version}" ]]; then
    (
cat <<-UPDATEINIT
""" ${name} package"""
__version__ = "${version}"
UPDATEINIT
    ) >$init
    git add $init
fi
```

Is there a better way that I've missed, as that hook seems a little 'clunky'.

Comment: What about reading the project version string from the project's own metadata? For example in `mytoplevelpackage/__init__.py`: `import importlib.metadata; __version__ = importlib.metadata.version('MyProject')`

Comment: `importlib` is no universal solution for python 3.6, 3.7, 3.8. Consistent behavior one can get using `pkg_resources` library. `pkg_resources.get_distribution('your-package').version` will give you the version.

Comment: Hey did you find some better way to do this?

Comment: If anyone was wondering the difference between `importlib` and `pkg_resources`, `importlib_resources is a library which provides for access to resources in Python packages. It provides functionality similar to pkg_resources Basic Resource Access API, but without all of the overhead and performance problems of pkg_resources.` from [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html). Also, `importlib` is fine for 3.7+, you can use the backport, `importlib_resources` for 3.6

Answer (score 1):

There is already a useful way to use the `pyproject.toml` using dynamic metadata  such as

```
[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
version = {attr = "my_package.__version__"}
readme = {file = "README.md"}
```

[From setuptools guide](https://%5Btool.setuptools.dynamic%5D%20version%20=%20%7Battr%20=%20%22my_package.VERSION%22%7D%20readme%20=%20%7Bfile%20=%20%5B%22README.rst%22,%20%22USAGE.rst%22%5D%7D%5Btool.setuptools.dynamic%5D%20version%20=%20%7Battr%20=%20%22my_package.VERSION%22%7D%20readme%20=%20%7Bfile%20=%20%5B%22README.rst%22,%20%22USAGE.rst%22%5D%7D)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).